# How do I change the width of an embedded tweet in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter

I am using the react-twitter-widgets library. My render function looks like this:

```
render() {
        return <div className="tweets">
            {this.state.loading ? <Spinner animation="border" role="status" variant='light'></Spinner> : <div></div>}
            {this.state.tweets.map((tweet) => {
                return(
                <Animated animationIn="fadeInLeftBig">
                    <Tweet options={{width: '550'}} tweetId={tweet.id_str}></Tweet>
                </Animated>
                )
            })}  
            </div>  
    }
```

However upon inspecting the Tweet element, it seems that the object prop changed the "max-width style".
[image]

I'm trying to change the "width" to its right. Changing the css like this didn't work.
[image]

Comment: Looks like an issue with the `<Tweet/>` component specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the Tweet component in a div and setting the div's width worked.